# PyQT Qscintilla Progress 4gl

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-4gl, qscintilla

I have been messing around with creating my own Progress 4GL Editor recently by implementing QsciLexerCustom in my python application. But while browsing through the Qscintilla Source i noticed they already have a progress 4gl lexer in QScintilla/lexers/LexProgress.cpp but while reading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla2/annotated.html they dont specify any QsciLexerProgress class or any means of accessing this lexer, that i can see.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Robert. Maybe this website will help: http://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QScintilla is apparently a port of Scintilla to use the [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29) GUI framework.  It probably requires a bit of work to port a lexer, so they probably just didn't spend the time porting the lexers for unpopular languages.

In other words, I think the .cpp file you found is just a remnant from Scintilla that never got ported over to QScintilla but is still in their code base.

Comment: Thanks i was afraid that was the case.

Comment: @RobertEdwards. This answer is completely wrong. Please see my answer for a proper explanation (and a potential solution).

Comment: @ekhumoro I wasn't implying the lexers had to be re-written, I meant there would be some work to get them working under QScintilla - which your post explains in detail.  Perhaps "port" wasn't the right word to use, but the fact that every lexer has to be wrapped in a "`QsciLexer*`" class I think proves my point.  This work simply wasn't done for the Progress lexer.

Comment: @AbeVoelker. Yes, the lexers don't need to be ported, and the .cpp file  isn't a "remnant" - it's part of the Scintilla library which is *compiled into* QScintilla. So all of the lexers are fully available to be used by Qscintilla, it's just that they need to be configured in order to work properly. That's what the `QsciLexer*` classes are for (and they are not a lot of work to create). Having said all that, the first sentence of your answer *is* correct - so perhaps "completely wrong" was slightly harsh ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `QSciLexer*` classes are misleadingly named. They aren't really lexers at all. Rather they provide a wrapper for the *properties files* used by the Scintilla-based editor, [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html). Properties files contain all the settings (fonts, colours, keywords, etc) that are required to configure a specific Scintilla lexer.

By default, QScintilla does not provide a `QsciLexer*` class for every language that Scintilla supports. It just provides ones for the most commonly used languages, plus any that are requested by users on the [mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/qscintilla). AFAIK, the author of Qscintilla is happy to add a `QsciLexer*` class for any language supported by Scintilla - the only requirement being that a usable SciTE properties file exists for the corresponding lexer.

Unfortunately, the current SciTE sources don't include a properties file for the Progress 4GL lexer! However, it's entirely possible that someone created one at some time, so a little searching will likely produce one. Failing that, you could always create one yourself.

PS: It's a real annoyance that QScintilla doesn't allow the `QsciLexer` class to be subclassed properly (some of the critical virtual functions aren't public). If it was, it would be possible to create a custom wrapper class for any language supported by Scintilla, without having to ask the author of Qscintilla to add one.